# Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device but I cant access the boot configuration or BIOS

Tags: boot, bios

I've tried everything, i pressed every key and watched every tutorial but all include having to open the BIOS or boot configuration but I cant.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Try this: Restart (slows things down) and go into BIOS, and try changing the Boot sequence this way

Comment: I don't see enough information to help you. Things like "tried everything" aren't helpful.  Are you saying that you can't access your UEFI firmware settings? (there is no bios).  If this is the case, restart windows and hold down shift when you click "restart".

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: If you are running Windows, the simplest solution, is to use Advance Startup or purposefully fail to boot into Windows.  However, without knowing what operating system you are actually running, your question cannot be answered by finding the appropriate duplicate.